# US date for Australian data downloaded from Yahoo using pandas web data reader

Tags: python, pandas, yahoo-finance, yahoo-api, quantitative-finance

If i download historical data for Australian stock market using the Pandas web data reader, it shows yesterdays date (this is most probably due to it being the day before (in the US) due to time zone differences. 
If i view this data on the Yahoo website is shows the correct Australian Date, The website must convert the date.

```
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import pandas as pd
yahoo_data = web.DataReader("^AXMJ", 'yahoo')
yahoo_data.tail()
```

The last date is shown as 
2017-11-16

But if you look at the website 
https://au.finance.yahoo.com/quote/%5EAXMJ/history?p=%5EAXMJ
the last date is 2017-11-17 which is the real last date.

What is the best way to convert the date? I know i can just shift the dates forward but i think there must be a more elegant way.

Comment: there was a recent [discussion](https://github.com/pydata/pandas-datareader/issues/315) on this. `web.DataReader("^AXMJ", 'yahoo', datetime.datetime(2017, 11, 12), datetime.datetime.now())` will throw a RemoteDataError

Comment: If you go the page for ^AXMJ, then Historical Data > Download Data -- this CSV is exactly what is retrieved by DataReader.  And that CSV runs only through 11/16 while the site itself shows 11/17.

Comment: But the values and dates are not matching, if you look at the download for the 16th, it will have the values for the website on the 17th.

Comment: It exports the data in US time zone at the time the data was recorded, i'm fine with this, i just want to know the best way to convert back to Australian time zone.

Comment: I've come to the conclusion that yahoo data is not suitable for live trading, its fine for some backtesting though